# npm replace: issue with npm script to replace text in multiple file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to replace keywords in multiple files within multiple folders.
I'm using below regex for path: `./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss`

npm script: `"build:src:replace:icon": "replace 'foo' 'bar' ./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss -r"`

> Note: This command is part of a `npm-script`. 
>   `replace` is failing
>   only when used inside `npm-script`.

Error:

```
 replace 'foo' 'bar' ./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss -r

Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
fs.js:941
  binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\XYZ\project\dist\src\**\**\**\*.scss'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:941:11)
    at replacizeFileSync (C:\Users\XYZ\project\node_modules\replace\replace.js:138:22)
    at module.exports (CC:\Users\XYZ\project\node_modules\replace\replace.js:79:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYZ\project\node_modules\replace\bin\replace.js:42:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@2.3.0 build:src:replace:icon: `replace 'foo' 'bar' ./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss -r`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@2.3.0 build:src:replace:icon script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your script inside the `scripts` section of your *package.json* to the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:src:replace:icon": "replace \"foo\" \"bar\" dist/src/ -r --include=\"*.scss\""
},
```

**Explanation:**

1. Note both the *find/change* strings, i.e. `foo` and `bar`, have been wrapped in JSON escaped double quotes `\"...\"`, instead of single quotes (`'...'`), for better cross-platform compatibility.
2. Your glob pattern has been changed from `./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss` to `dist/src/`.

   - Instead to using multiple unnecessary double stars, i.e. `.../**/**/**`, we don't specify any because we are using the `-r` (resursive) option.
   - The file extension `/*.scss` has also been omitted from your glob pattern
3. We utilize the `--include` option to target only the `.scss` files, i.e. `--include=\"*.scss\"`

Answer (score 0):

You shell is probably resolving the glob pattern leading to a weird behaviour. Try quoting the glob:

```
npm run replace "./dist/src/**/**/**/*.scss"
```

Comment: it's part of an npm script. Tried it; still the same issue.